# rellenar listview con dispositivos bluetooth

Tags: android, revisión-de-código

Estoy intentando rellenar un *listview* escaneando dispositivos bluetooth cercanos, pero no lo consigo. ¿Alguien ve algun fallo?

```java
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Seleccion extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView lista;
    BluetoothAdapter bAdapter;
    private static final int    REQUEST_ENABLE_BT   = 1;
    private ArrayList<String> mDeviceList = new ArrayList<String>();

    private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                System.out.println("aquiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii");
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                mDeviceList.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
                Log.i("BT", device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
                lista.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mDeviceList));
            }
        }
    };
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_seleccion);
        lista=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lista);

        bAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        bAdapter.startDiscovery();
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        this.unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    }
}
```

Y el Layout:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.oftecnica2.tabsbt.Seleccion"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="436dp"
        android:id="@+id/lista"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="RECARGAR"
        android:id="@+id/button3" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: error que te da?